# Import of module 'glog.glog.log_severity' appears within namespace 'google'

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I know this is duplicated, since the answered solution doesn't work for me, I'm asking again in case someone has come up with any new solution...

Already tried:

Unlinked all auto-linked modules and manually specified them in pod file.

Also tried

```
use_modular_headers!

pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec', :modular_headers => false
pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec', :modular_headers => false
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I also struggled with that issue and found came up with the solution.
Actually, I tried the same thing as you did but I found it wrong.

```js
use_modular_headers!

pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec', :modular_headers => false
pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec', :modular_headers => false
```

Adding this didn't solve the issue but I added only `glog` one and it worked.
I mean

```js
use_modular_headers!

pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec', :modular_headers => false
```

Adding only above code snippet solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

After lots of digging, I suspected maybe the module being imported may be in a separate folder, so I double checked my folder structure to make sure everything was okay.

Here's what I found.

[image: glog folder structure]

`log_severity.h` is in a subfolder named `glog`, so I changed the import statement to import from the subfolder, and this worked for me.

```
#include "glog/glog/log_severity.h"
```

I did the same for any other import statements trying to import modules found in the `glog` subfolder.

I got a warning while doing so saying the file is read-only, but I chose to overwrite it anyway, and the project built succesfully.

Comment: Amazing, this answer solves my problem. I am using Expo SDK 50, react-native: 0.73.4, using custom dev client by `expo prebuild`. Building on cloud using EAS is fine, but when I try to build locally it throws this error.

Answer (score 1):

I actually battled with this problem all night, eventually I cd into /ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog/glog/logging.h

Then I changed

FROM

- #include "glog/log_severity.h"
- #include "glog/vlog_is_on.h"

TO

- #include "glog/glog/log_severity.h"
- #include "glog/glog/vlog_is_on.h"
- force overwite
- Save
- then: npx expo run:ios again to restart