# React Native iOS build failing due to glog and React Logger

Tags: react-native

I have a react native app which is working fine on android but when i try to run `npx react-native run-ios` I'm getting the following error

```
2023-02-16 11:27:07.190 xcodebuild[10406:767829] [MT] IDEFileReferenceDebug: [Load] <IDESwiftPackageCore.IDESwiftPackageSpecialFolderFileReference, 0x7f95f65afc30: name:Docs.docc path:group:Docs.docc> Failed to load container at path: /Users/shubhagarwal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weedlemobiledapptraining-cngaloxjuncutwengkgnppfnmbtd/SourcePackages/checkouts/swift-protobuf/Sources/protoc-gen-swift/Docs.docc, Error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.IDEContainerErrorDomain Code=6 "Cannot open "Docs.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder"." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot open "Docs.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder".}
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/shubhagarwal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weedlemobiledapptraining-cngaloxjuncutwengkgnppfnmbtd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-logger.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/react_native_log.o /Users/shubhagarwal/Desktop/metawork/portal-react-native/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/logger/react_native_log.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'React-logger' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

If I try to build it via XCode, this is what the error looks like

[image: screenshot of XCode errors]

This is how my Podfile looks like

```
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/package.json')"`), "native_modules")
require 'json'
podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'Podfile.properties.json'))) rescue {}
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '12.0'
install! 'cocoapods',
:deterministic_uuids => false


target 'weedlemobiledapptraining' do
  use_expo_modules!
  use_modular_headers!
  # use_frameworks!

  config = use_native_modules!
  # use_frameworks! :linkage => podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks'].to_sym if podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks']

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled] || podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes',
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Dir.pwd}/.."
  )

  # Uncomment to opt-in to using Flipper
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work
  #
  # if !ENV['CI']
  #   use_flipper!()
  # end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end

  post_integrate do |installer|
    begin
      expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
  end

end
```

Versions :

node : 14.21.2
React : 17.0.2
React Native : 0.68.2
XCode : 12.1

I've tried everything that I could find on the internet.

Reinstalled Node Modules and Pods several times
Tried to make the build without use_frameworks! or use_modular_headers!
Adding glog to the podfile

Comment: Possible duplicate to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71125474/8581245), better check the answer under this question

Answer (score 0):

This question might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71125474/8581245), and I will paste [Victor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77994015/8581245) here which solves my issue.

> After lots of digging, I suspected maybe the module being imported may be in a separate folder, so I double checked my folder structure to make sure everything was okay.
>
> Here's what I found.
>
> [image: glog folder structure]
>
> `log_severity.h` is in a subfolder named glog, so I changed the import statement to import from the subfolder, and this worked for me.
>
> ```
> #include "glog/glog/log_severity.h"
> ```
>
> I did the same for any other import statements trying to import modules found in the glog subfolder.
>
> I got a warning while doing so saying the file is read-only, but I chose to overwrite it anyway, and the project built successfully.

My environment info:

- Expo SDK version: 50
- Expo Workflow: bare
- React Native version: 0.73.4